# How do I check for .ready on .load?

Tags: jquery

I want to check for the `.ready` function when loading a `div` frame.

```
$('#webbox').load('main.html');
```

Is this correct? :

```
$('#webbox').ready(function() {});
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: `.load()` has a "complete  callback, you can put your code there http://api.jquery.com/load/

Comment: If you are looking for the callback function when the content is loaded, supply this function as the second argument to .load().

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No it isn't. `.ready` only checks whether the whole DOM of the page is ready, you cannot use it for "sub parts" of the page (in fact, the selected elements are completely ignored when you are calling `.ready`).

Pass a callback to `.load` instead:

```
$('#webbox').load('main.html', function() {
    // content loaded
});
```

From the [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/load/):

> If a "complete" callback is provided, it is executed after post-processing and HTML insertion has been performed. The callback is fired once for each element in the jQuery collection, and `this` is set to each DOM element in turn.

Comment: Good and working answer, thanks! :)

Answer (score 0):

use:

```
$('#webbox').load('main.html', function() {
  // your code
});
```

as in [documentation API](http://api.jquery.com/load/)